# Map walking distance/time from transit stops

Tags: qgis, network, transportation

I'm working in QGIS and would like to show how far from a bus stop a pedestrian could walk along the street network in any direction for a specified set of walking times (5,10,20 mins etc).

I have my street network as a modified OS ITN Road Centre Line layer and bus stop locations as points.

Here's what i'm aiming for: http://www.humantransit.org/2010/05/culdesac-hell-and-the-radius-of-demand.html rather than isochrone/heat maps.

Many thanks

Comment: I suspect the problem here will that the OS ITN won't show the pedestrian paths and short cuts that you need. You might need to add OSM data in (or just use OSM).

Comment: Thanks Iant. I heard about the ITN limitations so I used OSM data to modify the ITN layer in order to capture pedestrian paths and short cuts.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the driving distance function of pgrouting, using distance or any formula for units. For example, I have a slope-dependant speed for cycling.

There's a great tutorial made by Anita (Underdark) here : [Catchment areas with pgrouting driving distance](http://anitagraser.com/2011/05/13/catchment-areas-with-pgrouting-driving_distance/)

Then you can union for each bus stop then select minimum for each of your network point.

Comment: Attempted to follow underdark's tutorial but alas it's too advanced for my GIS skills. Have opted to go manual and use the measure line then draw my polylines.

Answer (score 0):

ITN has an Urban Paths layer covering most towns and cities in the UK:  http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/urban-paths.html with paths through parks, cycle tracks etc.